# How do I make a vertical toolbar in landscape mode that rotates to become horizontal in portrait mode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, toolbar

I am creating an app for designing model railroad layouts.  I want to have a toolbar on the bottom and possibly on the top of the screen in portrait mode, and then when the user rotates their device to landscape, have the toolbars stay in the same place on the screen so that they are on the left and right sides of the screen and have the icons rotate, just like the toolbars in the built in camera app on iOS.  How can I do this?  Can I do this in interface builder in Xcode?  If not, what is the specific code?  Also, I am using Swift.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make the toolbar not rotate, here is the code:

```
import UIKit

class MainNavigationController: UINavigationController {

override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
   return false    
   }
}

class MainViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // Hide the navigation bar on the this view controller
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
    }

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    }
}
```

Basically, you have to embed a navigation controller into the view you want to not rotate, change the navigation controller's class to `MainNavigationController` and then hide the navigation bar, if desired.